# Node JS - Encrypt / Decrypt

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography

I have an encryption function like this

```
const encryptWithInitVector = (string, keyBase64, ivBase64) => {
  const key = Buffer.from(keyBase64, 'base64')
  const iv = Buffer.from(ivBase64, 'base64')

  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(getAlgorithm(keyBase64), key, iv)
  let encrypted = cipher.update(string, 'utf8', 'base64')
  encrypted += cipher.final('base64')
  return encrypted
}
```

that receives a string to be encoded, an AESKey and an initializationVector.

How can I make the reverse path? I want to decode the response of the function encryptWithInitVector

Comment: Depending on your mode of operation, the IV has to be either unique (CTR, CFB, OFB) or unpredictable (CBC) for every encryption with the same key. If you don't utilize unique IVs when you should, there is a catastrophic break, because now it is possible to deduce the plaintexts just by observing ciphertexts.

Comment: The IV is not supposed to be secret. Just generate a fresh random IV during every encryption and put it in front of the ciphertext. Then you can slice it off during decryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createdecipheriv_algorithm_key_iv_options

Create decipher using `crypto.createDecipheriv`

```
const decryptWithInitVector = (string, keyBase64, ivBase64) => {
  const key = Buffer.from(keyBase64, 'base64')
  const iv = Buffer.from(ivBase64, 'base64')

  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(getAlgorithm(keyBase64), key, iv)

  let decrypted = decipher.update(string,'base64','utf-8');
  decrypted += decipher.final('utf-8');
  return decrypted
}
```